# How to setup recent stable SELinux policies in Debian 8.7?

Tags: debian, selinux

I am following the step 12 of the guide [here](https://spreadprivacy.com/linux-privacy-tips-1dc956657357), but did not find any policies that are recent and stable, only "old" things there and unstable. 
Code and output

```
masi@masi:~$ apt search SELinux | grep selinux

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

android-libselinux/unstable 7.0.0+r1-2 amd64
android-libselinux-dev/unstable 7.0.0+r1-2 amd64
libselinux1/oldstable,oldstable,now 2.3-2 amd64 [installed]
libselinux1-dev/oldstable,oldstable 2.3-2 amd64
python-selinux/oldstable,oldstable 2.3-2 amd64
python3-selinux/unstable 2.6-3+b1 amd64
ruby-selinux/oldstable,oldstable 2.3-2 amd64
selinux-basics/oldstable,oldstable 0.5.2 all
selinux-policy-default/unstable 2:2.20161023.1-9 all
selinux-policy-dev/unstable 2:2.20161023.1-9 all
selinux-policy-doc/unstable 2:2.20161023.1-9 all
selinux-policy-mls/unstable 2:2.20161023.1-9 all
selinux-policy-src/unstable 2:2.20161023.1-9 all
selinux-utils/oldstable,oldstable 2.3-2 amd64
```

### Test 2

Completing steps [here](https://www.tecmint.com/mandatory-access-control-with-selinux-or-apparmor-linux/) to install `policycoreutils-python`. 
Code but failed dependencies

```
masi@masi:/etc/ssh$ sudo apt install policycoreutils-python-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 policycoreutils-python-utils : Depends: policycoreutils (= 2.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: python3-audit but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: python3-selinux (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: python3-semanage (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: python3-sepolgen (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: python3-sepolicy (= 2.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: libselinux1 (>= 2.6) but 2.3-2 is to be installed
                                Depends: libsepol1 (>= 2.6) but 2.3-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selinux isn't fully supported on debian jessie

[The debian handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.selinux.html)

> **CAUTION** Reference policy not in jessie
>
> Unfortunately the maintainers of the refpolicy source package did not handle release critical bugs on their package and the package got removed from jessie. This means that the selinux-policy-* packages are currently not installable in jessie and need to be fetched from another place. Hopefully they will come back in one of the point releases or in jessie-backports. In the meantime, you can grab them from unstable.
>
> This sad situation at least proves that SELinux is not very popular in the set of users/developers who are running the development versions of Debian. Thus, if you opt to use SELinux, you should expect the default policy to not work perfectly and you will have to invest quite some time to make it suitable to your specific needs.

The [`selinux-policy-default`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/admin/selinux-policy-default) package is only available for debian Wheezy , Stretch , Buster and Sid.

Comment: I hope an upgrade will come on this thing soon, since Jessie has been out there already long time.